# Problems with audio and video Muxing

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec

I'm modifying an audio encoder example for write audio and video both. I'm trying to get video raw data from device display by MediaProjection and get audio raw data from Microphone by AudioRecord. Then I will send them to MediaCodec(I will set two Codec instance).

After that I will send the video data and audio data to MediaMux to get a mp4 file. I have any problems:

1. In result I get a file with perfect video track but terrible audio track. Audio track have plays with intervals at the beginning of track and without pauses but very fast at the end.
2. When I play video with android MXPlayer all ok, but when I play with PC players (Windows Media or Media Player Classic) audio plays like on MXPlayer but video don't plays - shows only first frame.

[Sample of result video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmdrzmewh6wvqn5/test_1432289405394.mp4?dl=0):

Part of code:

```
/**
* Method run of EncoderTask
*/
public void run() {
    if (mIsInitialized) {
        switch (type) {
            case ENCODE_AUDIO_FRAME:
                if (!mStopReceived) {
                    _offerAudioEncoder(mAudioData, presentationTimeNs);
                    mDrainHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mEncodingService.submit(new EncoderTask(Encoder.this, EncoderTaskType.ENCODER_VIDEO_FRAME));
                        }
                    }, DELAY_MILLIS); // 10 milliseconds
                }
                break;
            case ENCODER_VIDEO_FRAME:
                if (!mStopReceived) {
                    encoder._offerVideoEncoder();
                    mDrainHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mEncodingService.submit(new EncoderTask(Encoder.this, EncoderTaskType.ENCODE_AUDIO_FRAME));
                        }
                    }, DELAY_MILLIS); // 10 milliseconds
                }
                break;
            case FINALIZE_ENCODER:
                finalizeEncoder();
                break;

        }
        // prevent multiple execution of same task
        mIsInitialized = false;
        mEncodingServiceQueueLength -= 1;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "run() called but EncoderTask not initialized");
    }
}

public void _offerVideoEncoder() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offer video");
    if (mStopReceived) {
        closeVideoEncoder();
        Log.d(TAG, "Offer video - stop");
    } else {
        drainEncoder(mVideoEncoder, mVideoBufferInfo, mVideoTrackIndex, false, "video");
        Log.d(TAG, "Offer video - drain");
        if (mStopReceived) {
            closeVideoEncoder();
            Log.d(TAG, "Offer video - stop");
        }
    }
}   

public void processAudioFrame() {
    long audioPresentationTimeNs = System.nanoTime();
    byte[] thisBuffer;
    if (mDataBuffer.isEmpty()) {
        thisBuffer = new byte[mSamplesPerFrame];
    } else {
        thisBuffer = mDataBuffer.poll();
    }

    mReadResult = mAudioRecorder.read(thisBuffer, 0, mSamplesPerFrame);
    if (VERBOSE) Log.i(TAG, "FillBuffer       real: " + String.valueOf(mBufferWriteIndex)
                + " - " + String.valueOf(mBufferWriteIndex + mReadResult - 1));

    if (mReadResult != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && mReadResult != AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
        mBufferWriteIndex = mBufferWriteIndex + mReadResult - 1;
        mTotalFramesWritten++;
        if (mAudioEncoder != null) {
            mAudioEncoder.offerEncoder(thisBuffer, audioPresentationTimeNs);
        }


        if (!mIsRecording && mAudioRecorder != null) {
            mAudioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(null);
            mAudioRecorder.release();
            mAudioRecorder = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "stopped");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Read error");
    }
}


private void _offerAudioEncoder(byte[] input, long presentationTimeNs) {
    if (audioBytesReceived == 0) {
        mAudioStartTime = presentationTimeNs;
    }

    mTotalInputAudioFrameCount++;
    audioBytesReceived += input.length;
    if (mEosSentToAudioEncoder && mStopReceived || input == null) {
        logStatistics();
        if (mEosReceived) {
            Log.d(TAG, "EOS received in offerAudioEncoder");
            closeAudioEncoder();
            mEosSentToAudioEncoder = true;
            if (!mStopReceived) {
                prepareAudioEncoder();
            } else {
                mEncodingService.shutdown();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    // transfer previously encoded data to muxer
    drainEncoder(mAudioEncoder, mAudioBufferInfo, mAudioTrackIndex, false, "audio");
    sendFrameToEncoder(input, presentationTimeNs);// send current frame data to encoder
}

private void sendFrameToEncoder(byte[] input, long presentationTimeNs) {
    try {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mAudioEncoder.getInputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mAudioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(input);
            if (mAudioSoftwarePoller != null) {
                mAudioSoftwarePoller.recycleInputBuffer(input);
            }
            long presentationTimeUs = (presentationTimeNs - mAudioStartTime) / 1000; // in microseconds
            if (mEosReceived) {
                mAudioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                closeAudioEncoder();
                mEosSentToAudioEncoder = true;
                if (mStopReceived) {
                    mEncodingService.shutdown();
                }
            } else {
                mAudioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void drainEncoder(MediaCodec encoder, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo, TrackIndex trackIndex, boolean endOfStream, String type) {
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 100;
    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
    while (true) {
        int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (!endOfStream) {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER " + type + " out of while");
                break;      // out of while
            } else {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no " + type + " output available, spinning to await EOS");
            }
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // not expected for an encoder
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED " + type);
            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();

        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
            if (mMuxerStarted) {
                throw new RuntimeException("format changed after muxer start");
            }
            MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat + ".");

            // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
            synchronized (mMuxer) {
                trackIndex.index = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                numTracksAdded++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Added " + type + " track index: " + trackIndex.index);
                if (numTracksAdded == TOTAL_NUM_TRACKS) {
                    mMuxer.start();
                    mMuxerStarted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, numTracksAdded + " tracks added. Muxer started");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "unexpected result from " + type + " encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " +
                    encoderStatus);
        } else {
            if (encodedData == null) {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "drainEncoder(" + endOfStream + ") " + type + " encodedData == null");
                throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus +
                        " was null");
            }
            if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
                bufferInfo.size = 0;
            }
            if (bufferInfo.size != 0) {
                if (!mMuxerStarted) {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "drainEncoder(" + endOfStream + ") " + type + " Muxer not started");
                    throw new RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started");
                }
                // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                encodedData.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
                synchronized (mMuxer) {
                    mMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex.index, encodedData, bufferInfo);
                }
            }

            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

            if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                if (!endOfStream) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "reached end of stream unexpectedly");
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "end of stream reached");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
}
```

Comment: You did not calculate the right pts for video and audio.

Answer (score 0):

I think in drainEncoder function you missed
`ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];` 
before 
       if (encodedData == null)